# how to use ajax in rails3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

As we know, Rails 3.1 is using CoffeeScript and JQuery.

The old way that I  handle the ajax request is respond the request to a template which name is **some_action.js.erb**

Now that we have CoffeeScript and I want my template could use coffeescript syntax.So what can I do?

Just changing the template file's suffix name?

**some_file.js.coffee** this works fine in the **assets/javascript** directory.

But I am handle the ajax request and its template is under the folder **views**,if just simply change the template name from **some_action.js.erb** to **some_action.js.coffee.erb** or **some_action.js.coffee**,it won't work,rails treat it like normal file and will not compile it from coffeescript syntax to normal javascript.

I am very sorry about my Enlgish ability,hope this time my question will explain my purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have upgraded to Rails 3.1, taking advantage of the new syntax is, like you suggested, as easy as converting your files over to CoffeeScript.

Now, you can't just name the file *.js.coffee and expect a conversion, but Ryan Bates at Railscasts recommends changing your files over manually as a great way of learning the syntax yourself. In fact, he has a screencast posted of him doing just that: http://railscasts.com/episodes/267-coffeescript-basics

Rails, then, will handle the compilation from js.coffee into .js for you.

Comment: I already seen the cast and perhaps I didn't made myself clear,I will edit my question again,please take a look at it

Comment: From what I gathered from your edit, you are keeping your some_action.js.coffee in your views folder, and hence not seeing correct compilation. It works, however, while you have it in your assets directory. May I simply suggest, then, that you keep the file in your assets directory? There, you can create whatever organizational hierarchy you'd like. If you'd still much prefer to keep your .js in views (to my understanding, this is non-idiomatic), I'd recommend doing some research into rails 3.1 asset pipeline paths.

Comment: thanks man,there is more much more about rails3.1 to explore for me